# No Password Prompt During Boot (Kubuntu 21.10)

Tags: boot, kubuntu, password, luks, prompt

I use Kubuntu 21.10, and have KDE 5.24.1, but this happened on older KDE versions, too. When I startup, I choose my installation from GRUB, and then I am presented with what should be the password prompt for Kubuntu, as my disk is LUKS encrypted.

Instead, what I get is the Kubuntu logo in the lower right hand corner, and nothing. Now, when I type, it's definitely registering the action, as I can input my password, and it will take me to my login screen like normal, but I can't actually see a prompt anywhere.

OS: Kubuntu 21.10
KDE: 5.24.1
Kernel: 5.13.03
Graphics Platform: X11